# How to colorize a grayscale image in Python OpenCV?

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, opencv, image-processing

So I have a grayscale image, it might have an alpha channel (transparency), it holds the intensity information but no color information.

Now I want to colorize it, meaning I have a single RGB color, any RGB color, and I want to combine the color and the image to produce a new monotone image. Without the grayscale image, the result would be an image with the same size as the grayscale image flood-filled with the given color. The grayscale image makes certain area lighter or darker, so that the new image has discernible features.

I tried to do it but the result is wrong:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

def colorize(img, rgb):
    grey = img[..., 0]
    channels = [grey * (channel / 256) for channel in rgb[::-1]]
    
    if img.shape[2] == 4:
        channels.append(img[..., 3])
    
    return np.dstack(channels).astype(np.uint8)
```

Original image:

[image]

My original image has transparency and I loaded it with `cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED` flag.

I want to colorize it with (128, 192, 255), the expected result from GIMP 2 is:

[image]

But I got this instead, the picture is way too dark:

[image]

---

I now realize to get the same effect as seen in GIMP 2 I need to create a flood filled image of the desired color and blend it with the source image with "hard light" as blending mode.

But semantically what I originally wanted to achieve is to replace the original image's hue component and saturation component of each pixel  with the new color's HS in the HSV color model, and use the original images lightness as the new image's lightness to add shading.

What I have just described is the HSL color blending mode.

Google searching anything more than a few words provides nothing relevant, but searching keywords `"blend mode"` gives me [Blend modes Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blend_modes) and [Blend modes CSS specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/compositing-1), I have also read [GIMP 2 docs](https://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-concepts-layer-modes.html).

There are no Python implementations listed, but that won't stop me. I am extremely intelligent and the formulas don't look that complicated, I can implement all 38 of them in a few hours and I will spend the rest of day implementing them. And I am learning C++ as well so I will also try to implement them in C++.

However I don't think if my custom implementation will be the most efficient, there are likely library methods that does at least part of the job and using them will increase efficiency, but I am unaware of those methods.

The `cv2` library provides 635 functions, and it would take a large amount of time for me to inspect all of them one by one.

I found them using the following:

```
import cv2
from pathlib import Path
from typing import Callable

cv2_functions = [f'cv2.{k}' for k, v in cv2.__dict__.items() if isinstance(v, Callable)]
Path('D:/cv2_functions.txt').write_text('\n'.join(cv2_functions))
```

I didn't use `inspect` because:

```
In [74]: import inspect

In [75]: inspect.isfunction(cv2.multiply)
Out[75]: False

In [76]: inspect.ismethod(cv2.multiply)
Out[76]: False

In [77]: inspect.iscode(cv2.multiply)
Out[77]: False
```

The existing answer implements the multiply blending mode which has the same effect as my original code and fails to give desired result.

New answers are required to implement hard light blend mode and HSL color blend mode, so I can know how to implement the blending modes more efficiently.

---

I am not seeking software recommendations here. The scope of the question is limited to `numpy` and `cv2` only, I am implementing the blend modes in `numpy`, but the `cv2` module offers 423 methods, some of them might have at least already done part of the work here, and so using these methods can make code more efficient, but I don't know which methods I can use.

So I want examples of implementing the blend modes using methods provided by `cv2`.

As for my purpose, I am currently writing a Tic-Tac-Toe game with AI and GUI in Python with PyQt6.

I have already completed the artificial intelligence part, but I am not familiar with GUI programming and I am struggling to create the GUI.

I want the user to be fully able to customize the GUI to change the color and style of everything, so I need to find ways to colorize the pictures on the fly.

When the program is complete I will post the program on Code Review, and I will then try to re-implement the program in C++ in accordance with feedback.

I have already implemented most of the blend modes, and I am implementing the rest of them. Here is a selection of them, I won't post all of them so that the question won't be cluttered by code, and I will post a separate question for them because I don't know how to blend images with alpha channel, the formulas said nothing about transparency:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2


def scale_down(base: np.ndarray, top: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
    return base / 255, top / 255


def scale_up(img: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
    return (img * 255).astype(np.uint8)


def blend_overlay(base: np.ndarray, top: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
    mask = base >= 0.5
    result = np.zeros_like(base)
    result[~mask] = (mult_2 := (2 * base * top))[~mask]
    result[mask] = (2 * base + 2 * top - mult_2 - 1)[mask]
    return result


def blend_hardlight(base: np.ndarray, top: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
    return blend_overlay(top, base)


def blend_multiply(base: np.ndarray, top: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
    return base * top


def blend_screen(base: np.ndarray, top: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
    return base + top - base * top


def blend_softlight(base: np.ndarray, top: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
    return (1 - 2 * top) * base**2 + 2 * base * top


def blend_colorburn(base: np.ndarray, top: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
    result = np.zeros_like(base)
    result[ones := base == 1.0] = 1
    result[zeros := top == 0.0] = 0
    mask = (~ones == ~zeros) == (ones == 0)
    result[mask] = 1 - np.minimum(1, (1 - base[mask]) / top[mask])
    return result
```

Comment: A little experiment with **ImageMagick** suggests to me that you want `overlay` blending mode rather than `hardlight`. You can find code that does overlay blending here https://github.com/flrs/blend_modes/blob/master/blend_modes/blending_functions.py#L839

Comment: My experiment with **ImageMagick** was `magick -size 100x100 xc:"rgb(128,192,255)" 5jFRo.png -compose overlay -composite result.png` You can get a list of all available blending modes with `magick identify -list compose` and try them out by replacing `overlay` in the foregoing command.

Comment: The transparency is completely separate. Just separate it out from your input image and do the blending just using three channels, then at the end, put it back into the processes image. Fred's answer (fmw42) shows how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works fine for me in Python/OpenCV.

- Read the input as unchanged
- Create a blue image as float (1,0,0)
- Separate the BGR channels and alpha channel from the input
- Convert the BGR image to float
- Multiply the BGR and alpha images and convert back to uint8
- Put the alpha channel back into the multiplied image
- Save the result
- Show the result

Note that the shown result will not show the transparency.  That might be your issue if you just viewed it rather than saving it.

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# read the image unchanged
img = cv2.imread('gray_circle.png', cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
hh, ww = img.shape[:2]

# define color image as blue
color_img = np.full((hh,ww,3), (1,0,0), dtype=np.float32)

# separate bgr channels and alpha channel from img
bgr = img[:,:,0:3]
alpha = img[:,:,3]

# multiply bgr with color_img
bgr = bgr.astype(np.float32)
mult = cv2.multiply(bgr, color_img)
mult = mult.astype(np.uint8)

# put alpha channel back
result = cv2.cvtColor(mult, cv2.COLOR_BGR2BGRA)
result[:,:,3] = alpha

# save result
cv2.imwrite('gray_circle_blued.png', result)

# show result
cv2.imshow('result', result)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Result:

[image]